# Add line break after caption title in R Markdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, kable

I am wanting to change the styling of captions in the R Markdown output, and have two requests:

1. How do you make the caption label bold?
2. How can you add a linebreak after the caption label? For example, I want to enter a line between "Table 1" and the caption.

Here is an example:

```
caption <- 
  " April is the cruellest month, breeding
    Lilacs out of the dead land, mixing
    Memory and desire, stirring
    Dull roots with spring rain.
    Winter kept us warm, covering
    Earth in forgetful snow, feeding
    A little life with dried tubers.
    Summer surprised us, coming over the Starnbergersee
    With a shower of rain; we stopped in the colonnade,
    And went on in sunlight, into the Hofgarten,
    And drank coffee, and talked for an hour.
    Bin gar keine Russin, stamm’ aus Litauen, echt deutsch.
    And when we were children, staying at the arch-duke’s,
    My cousin’s, he took me out on a sled,
    And I was frightened. He said, Marie,
    Marie, hold on tight. And down we went.
    In the mountains, there you feel free.
    I read, much of the night, and go south in the winter."

kable(mtcars, format = 'latex', caption = caption)
```

Comment: Describe what exactly your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `caption` package from LaTeX to control the outputs to PDF. We need to change some of the settings of this file to achieve your changes, but these can be included either as a separate `.tex` file, or in this case where only a few changes need to be made, we can just insert them within the frontmatter directly. Here is a minimal example:

````
---
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{caption}
   - \captionsetup{labelfont=bf, labelsep = newline}
---

```{r table1}
caption <- "your long long long caption"
knitr::kable(mtcars, caption = caption)
```
````

[image]

This approach only works for LaTeX outputs (i.e. PDF).

> If you want to make more changes to the style, check out the package documentation here: http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf

Comment: how would you add text by "Table 1". i.e "Table 1: Awesome Table".

Comment: By not including 'labelsep = newline'